# What is a good way to test that a Java method is synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, synchronization, thread-safety

I have several classes that implement some interface.  The interface has a contract, that some methods should be synchronized, and some should not, and I want to verify that contract through unit tests for all the implementations.  The methods should use the synchronized keyword or be locked on `this` - very similar to the synchronizedCollection() wrapper.  That means I should be able to observe it externally.

To continue the example of [Collections.synchronizedCollection()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedCollection(java.util.Collection)) if I have one thread calling iterator(), I should still be able to get into methods like add() with another thread because iterator() should not do any locking.  On the other hand, I should be able to synchronize on the collection externally and see that another thread blocks on add().

**Is there a good way to test that a method is synchronized in a JUnit test?  I want to avoid long sleep statements.**

Comment: Do you mean you want to test if they have the 'synchronized' keyword in their declaration? Or do you mean automatically test to see if the class is subject to some threading issues ... ?

Comment: Do you have the sources? You can see in the source whether a method is synchronized or not (find the `synchronized` statement in the body).
By the way, testing a class for a "good" thread-safeness is extremely difficult, and probably needs a lower-level code-inspection/analysis tool.

Comment: Checking for the synchronized keyword simply isn't enough. Synchronization can be enforced via Locks too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A big thank you to Zwei steinen for writing up the approach I used.  There are a few problems in the example code that I worked through, so I thought it would be worth posting my findings here.

- The call to join() expects a number of milliseconds, not nanoseconds.
- The two threads must be coordinated, otherwise the attempt thread can start and finish all before the locker thread grabs the lock.
- The attempt thread should not be started until after we record the start time.  Otherwise that thread gets enough of a head start that the recorded time can be slightly less than the timeout, causing spurious failures.

Here is the synchronization test code as a Scala trait:

```
trait SynchronizedTestTrait
{
    val classUnderTest: AnyRef

    class Gate
    {
        val latch = new java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch(1)

        def open()
        {
            this.latch.countDown
        }

        def await()
        {
            this.latch.await
        }
    }

    def nanoTime(code: => Unit) =
    {
        val before = System.nanoTime
        code
        val after = System.nanoTime
        after - before
    }

    def assertSynchronized(code: => Unit)
    {
        this.assertThreadSafety(threadSafe = true, millisTimeout = 10L)(code)
    }

    def assertNotSynchronized(code: => Unit)
    {
        this.assertThreadSafety(threadSafe = false, millisTimeout = 60L * 1000L)(code)
    }

    def assertThreadSafety(threadSafe: Boolean, millisTimeout: Long)(code: => Unit)
    {
        def spawn(code: => Unit) =
        {
            val result = new Thread
            {
                override def run = code
            }
            result.start()
            result
        }

        val gate = new Gate

        val lockHolderThread = spawn
        {
            this.classUnderTest.synchronized
            {
                // Don't let the other thread start until we've got the lock
                gate.open()

                // Hold the lock until interruption
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE)
                }
                catch
                {
                    case ignore: InterruptedException => return;
                }
            }
        }

        val measuredNanoTime = nanoTime
        {
            // Don't start until the other thread is synchronized on classUnderTest
            gate.await()
            spawn(code).join(millisTimeout, 0)
        }

        val nanoTimeout = millisTimeout * 1000L * 1000L

        Assert.assertEquals(
            "Measured " + measuredNanoTime + " ns but timeout was " + nanoTimeout + " ns.",
            threadSafe,
            measuredNanoTime > nanoTimeout)

        lockHolderThread.interrupt
        lockHolderThread.join
    }
}
```

Now let's say we want to test a simple class:

```
class MySynchronized
{
    def synch = this.synchronized{}
    def unsynch = {}
}
```

The test looks this:

```
class MySynchronizedTest extends SynchronizedTestTrait
{
    val classUnderTest = new MySynchronized


    @Test
    def synch_is_synchronized
    {
        this.assertSynchronized
        {
            this.classUnderTest.synch
        }
    }

    @Test
    def unsynch_not_synchronized
    {
        this.assertNotSynchronized
        {
            this.classUnderTest.unsynch
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to check if a method has the `synchronized` modifier, aside from the obvious (looking at the source code/Javadoc), you can also use reflection.

```
Modifier.isSynchronized(method.getModifiers())
```

The more general question of testing if a method guarantees proper synchronization in all concurrency scenarios is likely to be an undecidable problem.

Comment: What if it using a `synchronized` block inside?

Comment: Hmm I see that the question description has been edited to add a lot more new information now...

Answer (score 4):

These are all horrible ideas, but you could do this...

### 1

```
    // Substitute this LOCK with your monitor (could be you object you are
    // testing etc.)
    final Object LOCK = new Object();
    Thread locker = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Interrupted.");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    locker.start();

    Thread attempt = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do your test.
        }
    };

    attempt.start();
    try {
        long longEnough = 3000 * 1000;// It's in nano seconds

        long before = System.nanoTime();
        attempt.join(longEnough);
        long after = System.nanoTime();

        if (after - before < longEnough) {
            throw new AssertionError("FAIL");
        } else {
            System.out.println("PASS");
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        return;
    }
    locker.interrupt();
```

### 2

If you know that methods on the arguments are always invoked in any implementation, you can pass a mock object that disguises as the argument and calls holdsLock().

So like:

```
class Mock implements Argument {
    private final Object LOCK;
    private final Argument real;
    public Mock(Object obj, Argument real){
       this.LOCK=obj;
       this.real = real;
    }

    @Overrides
    public void something(){
        System.out.println("held:"+Thread.holdsLock(LOCK));
        this.real.something();
    }
```

Then wait for the class to invoke something() on Argument.

Comment: would only work if the class being tested uses a public monitor

Comment: This does answer what I'm looking for but I'm concerned about the sleep statements.

Comment: @matt b: Well, since he says it synchronizes on "this" I think that requirement is satisfied. I have a long sleep statement though...

Answer (score 1):

Using reflection, get the method's Method object, and invoke toString() on it.  The "synchronized" keyword should appear in toString()'s output.

Comment: Synchronized methods do not per se have a synchronized keyword. They can also use a `synchronized(this){...}` block.